# A problem on vector space( included in the attached image)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, change-of-basis

I cannot determine the approach to solve problems like this, so any help will be appreciated. I need help specifically with the third term on the right, as in the equation to be solved.

[image]

I would be grateful if someone can prove this in a detailed manner.

Comment: In the future, please take the time to enter important parts of your question as text instead of pasting a picture. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers, nor do they appear in summaries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go and review the Gram-Schmidt method.

What the problem says is:  You want a basis for the space spanned by $ U, x, v $.  You can add to the basis by first computing the component of $ v $ orthogonal to $ U $, call it $ w $,then the component of $ x $ orthogonal to $ U $, let's call it $ z $, and then the component of $ z $ orthogonal to the vector $ w $.